# Browsing to local DNS addresses instead of using them as a search query, without prefixing http

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dns, browser

If you try to enter a DNS address that isn't a public website, say, `myinternalhomepage.lan`, the first response from the average web browser like Chrome or Firefox will be to treat them as plaintext to be sent to a search engine, rather than connect to them as if they were a web address. But with public addresses it works fine, I can just enter `google.com` and get Google.

I understand that it's possible to force these to be directly connected to instead of searched by prefixing them with `http://` or `https://`, but this is fairly annoying.

Is there a configuration setting, either in the browser, or in the operating system, to treat certain URLs as connectable by default, so that manually entering the protocol prefix isn't necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly no.

However, you can accomplish this using a Chrome Extension.

[No Search For Local Hosts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-search-for-local-hosts/dmkiehihddlkkdaenlbeklkhhpdkoalk) is one such extension. This one enables you to configure it for specific local hosts by adding the top-level domain to its list. So for your example `myinternalhomepage.lan`, you would add `lan` to the extension's list of TLDs to force direct navigation to the URL rather than searching.

Answer (score 0):

I also found it is possible to override this behavior by suffixing the URL with a `/`, as in `myinternalhomepage.lan/` - this is at least more natural to type than `http://` at the beginning. I still prefer the extension given in the other answer, though!